# (Android)Menu Icon image is not display properly in different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, icons, menuitem

I have created menu as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/edit_or_save_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/edit_button"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/edit_or_save_button"/> 

</menu>
```

But here edit_button icon looks small in one device and bigger in another device as attached in screen shot. I have tried by putting images in **different drawable(xhdpi,hdpi,ldpi)** but it is not changing.

[image]

[image]

What is the problem here?Please guide me on this.

Comment: the edit images  in xhdpi,hdpi,ldpi folders have the same resolution?

Comment: @Metalhead1247 : No.they are in the ratio of 75,100,150,200.

Comment: since the other device is a hdpi/xhdpi its using image of 150 or 200

Comment: what do you mean by 150 or 200? Are you saying that size is 150 x 200?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the smaller Edit image on all devices

paste the 75 ratio / 100 ratio in all the drawable folders xhdpi,hdpi,ldpi and mdpi.

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density Devices

res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density   Devices

res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density Devices

ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).

mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi).

hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).

xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

As you want the same  small **edit button** on all devices paste the same small image in all drawable folders xhdpi,hdpi,ldpi and mdpi.

You can test on a emulator how it would look on different devices!

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Comment: no I dont want smaller edit button.I want edit button should be like first screen shot for all the devices(no smaller/no big but Normal size).I checked by resizing that image but it doesnt reflecting.

Comment: I have tried your method but image is displayed always small on emulator.I cant check on different devices because I have only one device.

Comment: @Ponting which is the smallest resolution image you have ?

Comment: edit_button's size is : 56x28.Is it problem when i run in emulator?Because I checked in emulator with different screen resolution but image's size is not changing.

Comment: @Ponting paste the 56x28 image in Hdpi and mdpi and remove edit_button image from xhdpi and ldpi it will work

Comment: I think the problem is in emulator because irrespective of creating emulator of smaller density or larger density by creating different screen size's emulator,edit_button's size remain same.

Comment: I tried by paste the 56x28 image in Hdpi and mdpi and remove edit_button image from xhdpi and ldpi.But it will still dispaying as smaller size image.

Comment: @Ponting you only said you wanted the small image on all devices

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37657/discussion-between-metalhead1247-and-ponting)